# Cannot output HTML attributes from the JSON object

Tags: angular

I have a JSON object. It looks like the following:

```
schema = [
      {
          "group": "class=\"col-lg-6\"",
          "label": {
              "text": "Full Name", 
              "attributes": "class=\"control-label\" for=\"FullName\""
          },
          "control": {
              "attributes": "class=\"form-control\" name=\"FullName\""
          }
      }
  ]
```

I'm looping the items of the JSON object in HTML and trying to output the HTML attributes to the div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let item of schema;" {{ item.group }}>
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">{{ item.label.text }}</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When doing so I get the following error message.

> ERROR Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{' is
> not a valid attribute name.

Here's the [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-ganguly-6d2568?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Looks like setting a class like you are doing with `{{ item.group }}` isn't going to work.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use databinding to dynamically place an attribute. You will have to extract the value in TS. Can you tell us is there are some constraints on the `group` value ? Is it always a class ? Or can it be any style ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle it's not going to be always class. It can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot bind the attribute as is. You have to tell the angular which attributes you are going to make dynamic. i.e. You can only bind the values.

One thing you can do is to separate the response as key-value pairs, provided the key is the known attribute.